# calcular un valor dinámico en una tabla generada automáticamente, solucionar error

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente:

Genero una tabla con datos que obtengo desde la `BDD` y hago los cálculos, esto no es el problema ya esta resuelto, el asunto es que necesito un `input` donde pueda ingresar un valor (interes) y este valor debe realizar calculo con la tabla ya generada o como se pueda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago el ingreso de otro valor en el `input` por consola estoy mostrando esos datos para ver cuales me generan problemas, y el error es con los datos llamados desde la `BDD`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código JS;

```
function Generar_Datos_depr(datos) {
var anios_presupuesto =  parseFloat(document.getElementById('años_proyectos').value);
var anios_dep = Number(datos.anos_depreciacion);  //VALOR DE BDD
var interes = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_interes').value); //INPUT
var precio = Number(datos.adquisi_depre) //VALOR DE BDD
var elementos = new Array();
var contador = 0
var globalizacion = interes / 100;

console.log(anios_presupuesto, anios_dep, interes,globalizacion, precio, elementos)
var cadena = '';
var valor = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < anios_presupuesto; i += (anios_dep)) {

    for (var j = 0; j < anios_dep + 1; j++) {

        valor = precio / anios_dep

        if (j == 0) {
            elementos.push(0);
        } else {
            elementos.push(valor)
        }
        if ((contador) <= anios_presupuesto) {
            cadena = cadena + `<td class="pre-d td_cant"><input type="text" name="" onkeyup="Generar_Datos_depr(this.value)" value="${(elementos[contador]).toFixed(2)}" readonly></input></td>`
        }
        contador++
    }
    precio = precio * (1 + globalizacion)
}
return cadena;
}
```

> Bueno, los datos de la `BDD` los estoy pasando como parámetro, así que no es necesario mostrarlo aquí, en todo caso de necesitarlo lo agrego después..!

Código obtener datos de BDD

```
var id_proyecto = document.getElementById('id_proyecto').value;
  fetch('/api/flujos_depre/' + id_proyecto)
.then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
    var cadena = ``
    response.forEach(datos => {
        cadena += `<tr class="t_fila_inv_a tr_cant">
                        <td class="pre-i "><input type="text" name="" onkeyup="Generar_Datos_depr(this.value)" value="${datos.concepto_depre}" readonly></td>
                        ${Generar_Datos_depr(datos)}
                    </tr>`
    });
    cadena += ``
    document.getElementById('flujo_depreciacion').innerHTML = cadena;
});
```

Comment: Para saber cómo vienen los valores de base de datos haz un `console.log(datos.anos_depreciacion, datos.adquisi_depre);`

Comment: @Triby, https://prnt.sc/sc70bc una capture con los datos que me pediste.

Comment: Ese juego de números es igual al que pusiste en la primera imagen `BDD INPUT` y no son los causantes del problema, sino los que vienen después de el error `Dev tools ...`. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código con el que obtienes la información de BDD

Comment: @Triby, si eso lo se, pero ese error pasa cuando ingreso el valor del `input`, igual ya agrego el codigo.

Comment: En el `input` tienes este evento `onkeyup="Generar_Datos_depr(this.value)"` y el valor `value="${datos.concepto_depre}"` parece ser texto. Lógicamente, no estás enviando los datos adecuados a la función y por eso el error.

Comment: ese `input` debe ser  `type="text"`, por que lo que recibe son caracteres, texto, que otro `type` puedo pones si lo que recibe son caracteres ??
aun así poniendo `type="number"`, sigue sin funcionar.
y el evento tampoco afecta (osea si lo quito el error sigue igual).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107708/discussion-between-duvalad-and-triby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:

En el código donde obtengo los datos de la `BDD` lo hice una función, y en esa función obtengo el valor del `input`que quiero envié valores (disculpen la redundancia), y lo paso como parametro para que en la función donde me hace los cálculos los pueda usar, así como `datos`.

Input:

```
<input type="number" onkeyup="ejecutar_tabla()" id="valor_interes" value="0">
```

Código JS:

```
function ejecutar_tabla() {
var id_proyecto = document.getElementById('id_proyecto').value;
var interes = parseFloat(document.getElementById('valor_interes').value);
fetch('/api/flujos_depre/' + id_proyecto).then((response) => 
    response.json()).then((response) => {
    var cadena = ``
    response.forEach(datos => {
        cadena += `<tr class="t_fila_inv_a tr_cant">
                        <td class="pre-i ">
                           <input type="text" value="${datos.concepto_depre}">
                         </td>
                        ${Generar_Datos_depr(datos, interes)}
                    </tr>`
    });
    cadena += ``
    document.getElementById('flujo_depreciacion').innerHTML = cadena;

});
}
ejecutar_tabla()
```

y por ultimo como decia la otra funcion donde hago el calculos de las filas, obtengo ese valor como parametro y ya solo es utiliarlo como quiera:

```
function Generar_Datos_depr(datos, interes) {  //parametro "interes"
  var anios_presupuesto = parseFloat(document.getElementById('años_proyectos').value);
  var globalizacion = interes / 100;    //Aquí lo utilizo
  var anios_dep = Number(datos.anos_depreciacion);  //VALOR DE BDD
  var precio = Number(datos.adquisi_depre); //VALOR DE BDD
  var elementos = new Array();
  var contador = 0
}
```

> agrego el ultimo código "corto" por que es lo único que cambia, el resto sigue igual a como estaba en la pregunta.